# Export datatable with 1 million records to csv

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, export-to-csv

I have a C# Data Table with about one million rows with 20 columns 
I need to export this to csv , i tried string builder but page keep loading

```
 public ActionResult DownloadExcel()
        {   
            System.Data.DataTable result = Helpers.TaxMailingExcelBuilder.Export();

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=myData.csv");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = @"application/text";
            Response.Output.Write(ExportDataTable(result).ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

            return View();
        }

        private StringBuilder ExportDataTable(System.Data.DataTable dt)
        {           
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + ',');
                }
                stringBuilder.Append("rn");
            }
            return stringBuilder;
        }
    }
```

page keep loading without any progress

Comment: Not great to have a huge string in memory.... Might want consider streaming the response...

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: What do you mean by *page keep loading*?

Comment: @Guy page keep loading for long time that exceed 15 Min , then i close it manually .

Comment: What page are you talking about? what it has to do with passing DB to excel?

Comment: yes , i have a button called export , it should download one million records to csv

Comment: @Bassem The last comment doesn't explain anything. Please edit your question to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain ***exactly*** what is the problem.

Comment: hello , @guy  , it is so simple , I have datatable object with million rows 20 column
need to export it to csv on user click !

Answer (score 1):

I would return a StringWriter like code below

```
       private StringWriter ExportDataTable(DataTable dt)
       {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

            string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

            foreach(DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row.ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString())));
            }
            return writer;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks @jdweng  I apply this but it keep loading for long time , i left my pc for an hour and when i come back i found it still loading , do you have any idea :(

Comment: Are you calling the method more than once?  when the code is running open Task Manager and check memory usage?  If it is running very slow it is probably due to insufficient memory and the Hard Drive is being used as virtual memory.

Comment: I checked the task manager , it is fine , no problem with it 
I make another way instead of using mysqlDatareader to fill the datatable , I directly write to the file using your solution while reading the data from DB , while myReader.read() , but still very slow , is there any alternative faster  solution :(

Comment: MySQL isn't designed to handle huge databases.  I don't know how you are connecting to the database.  The quickest method is using a data context object (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html).

Comment: I am using Ado and SqlDataReader

Comment: while (rdr.Read())
                    {                      
                        for (int j = 0; j < 22; j++)
                        {
                            writer.Write(string.Join(",",rdr[j].ToString().Replace(',', ';')));
                        }
                        writer.WriteLine();
                    }
                    rdr.Close();

Comment: but rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); is exist in a for loop , it is executed about 100 times with different limit ,  limit 0,5000    , limit 5001 ,5000 , etc

Comment: Why do you need create a datatable?  Can't you simple read using cmdExecuteReader and then write each result to the file?

Comment: thats what i did , i am not using datatable and it is still slow , please advice

Comment: Which is slow?  The reading of the database or the writing of the file?  Do one at a time and see how much time each takes.  If it is the writing of the file try writing to c: drive and see if that makes a differences

Comment: man i appreciate your fast response and your support , look , when i try to read from DB one time without limit , it gives memory exception , when i try to save on C , it gives access denied , reading from DB on multiple chunks is get all data in about 10 min but gives memory exception when writing

Comment: please try to format this code and check it 
this part is executed about 100 times 
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000000;
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{ 
                        for (int j = 0; j < 22; j++)
                        {
writer.Write(string.Join(",", rdr[j].ToString().Replace(',', ';')));
                        }
                        writer.WriteLine();
 }
start = start + length + 1;
rdr.Close();

after this loop i return writer

Comment: I'm not sure this will help but it is much better in writing the file.  You do not need to for loop.                       object[] rowItems = new object[rdr.FieldCount];
            rdr.GetSqlValues(rowItems);
            string[] strItems = rowItems.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", strItems));

Comment: wow , it become faster and return the writer faster but this line gives System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.'

Comment: Response.Output.Write(Helpers.Export());

Comment: Export is the function which return the writer